# WSSecHeader insertSecurityHeader

Tags: java

Error:WRONG_DOCUMENT_ERR: A node is used in a different document than the one that created it.
Version library org.apache.ws.security:wss4j:1.6.192

```
private static final String SIMPLE_XML_SOAP = "<soapenv:Envelope></soapenv:Envelope>"; 

InputStream is2 = new ByteArrayInputStream(SIMPLE_XML_SOAP.getBytes()); 

SOAPMessage msg2 = MessageFactory.newInstance().createMessage(null, is2); 

SOAPEnvelope env2 = msg2.getSOAPPart().getEnvelope();

System.out.println(env2.getOwnerDocument()); 

WSSecHeader secHeader2 = new WSSecHeader(); 

secHeader2.setMustUnderstand(true); secHeader2.insertSecurityHeader(env2.getOwnerDocument());
```